# Hibernate: how to map one-to-many with another database?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 classes: User and Message. 
One user can have several messages. 
I.e. this is association one-to-many. 
My users table is in first database and the messages table in the second database. 
How can I map them?

My users and messages tables mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.example.hibernate.User" table="users" lazy="false">
    <id name="xId" type="int" column="xid" >
            <generator class="increment"/>   
    </id>

    <set name="messages" inverse="true" table="messages">
        <key>
            <column name="xsin_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.example.hibernate.Message" />
     </set>     
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.example.hibernate.Message" table="messages" lazy="false">
       <id name="id" type="int" column="xmsgbox" >
        <generator class="increment"/>     
       </id>

       <many-to-one name="user" class="com.example.hibernate.User">
               <column name="xsin_id" not-null="true" />
           </many-to-one>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**I also have 2 *.cfg.xml files where these classes are mapped.**

My test code snipplet:

```
Session session = HibernateUtilUser.getSession();

String SQL_QUERY ="from User user";
Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
User user = null;
for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();){
    user=(User)it.next();               
    break;
}
Set<Message> messages = user.getMessages();
assertNotNull(messages);
```

I get an error: **Association references unmapped class: com.example.hibernate.Message**

P.S. my HibernateUtilUser class:

```
public class HibernateUtilUser {

    private static SessionFactory sf;
    private static Session session;

    private HibernateUtil() {}

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {      
        if (sf == null) {
            sf = new Configuration().configure("hibernateuser.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        }       
        return sf;      
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        if (session == null || session.isOpen() == false) {
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
        }       
        return session;
    }

    public Session openSession() {
        return sf.openSession();
    }

    public static void close(){
    if (sf != null)
        sf.close();
        sf = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving DB name in table proeprty, like table="[your another DB Name]..messages"

```
<set name="messages" inverse="true" table="AnotherDB..messages"> 
        <key> 
            <column name="xsin_id" not-null="true" /> 
        </key> 
        <one-to-many class="com.example.hibernate.Message" /> 
     </set>
```

Comment: We have two different sessions for two databases, so I want to configure many-to-one reationship for different database tables.
  projects table in pms database and commonlookupdetails table in admin database, can you help me how to mapping these two tables in many-to-one relation
  
  <many-to-one name="commonLookupDetails" column="status" foreign-key="detailId" fetch="select" lazy="proxy" not-found="ignore" update="false" insert="false" class="com.pb.oas.pms.data.hibernate.CommonLookupDetails"></many-to-one>

Comment: It shows an error Association references unmapped class: com.pb.oas.pms.data.hibernate.CommonLookupDetails                      Can you help me Ms.Jothi

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems working
[link text](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1002191&start=0)

```
You need to use one SessionFactory only. Then, in the mapping files for your classes, use the schema or catalog attributes. For example:

Code:
<class name="Test1" table="Test1" catalog="...">

<class name="Test2" table="Test2" catalog="...">


This of course assumes that the databases lives in the same MySQL server.
```